# How to test connect the MySQL in Django?

Tags: mysql, django

In the Django project's `settings.py`, there is the DATABASES config:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'csvt',
        'USER':'root',
        'PASSWORD':'123456',
        'HOST':'127.0.0.1',
        'PORT':'3306',
    }
}
```

Now, I even don't know the password if is correct, how can I test the connect with my MySQL on my Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try testing when creating migrations or creating admin user.

run this on terminal. On your django root folder.

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

If you are able to create a super user. Then you can access your Django Admin page. in http://your_base_url/admin